# password wrong still sends you to the next page

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I started coding in c# 2 days ago for school so I'm very new to it, I ran into a problem with my code and I don't know how to fix it. Once the person trying to login has 3 failed attempts it indeed shows the text that tells the user that they failed 3 times and that the app will close itself, but instead of closing the app sends them to the next "page" with the text menu on it. I have tried multiple things and asked friends in school but no one really knows what's wrong with the code.

If someone who is more experienced knows I'd really appreciatie it, if there is anything else wrong with my code or if I made a mistake please let me know, I'd like to learn as much as possible!

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Gimpies
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // strings inlognaam + password
            string inlognaam = "inkoop";
            string password = "Gimpies_Inkoop";

            // attempts counter
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                // strings gebruikersnaam + wachtwoord
                Console.WriteLine("U heeft nog " + (3 - i) + " pogingen ");
                Console.WriteLine("Voor gebruikersnaam in:");
                string gebruikersnaam = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Voer wachtwoord in:");
                string wachtwoord = Console.ReadLine();


                // If else login / password
                if (inlognaam == gebruikersnaam && password == wachtwoord)
                {                                      
                    Console.WriteLine("Succes");    
                    Console.WriteLine("Druk een knop in om door tegaan");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    goto AfterLoop;
                    
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist probeer opnieuw.");
                                                             
            }

            Console.WriteLine("U heeft geen poginen meer, de applicatie sluit af na 5 seconden");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

        AfterLoop:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Menu");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

we have tried adding in the break; command instead of Thread.sleep but that ruined the loop ofcourse, and we have also messed around with the ReadKey but that didnt't help aswell

Comment: `goto AfterLoop;` - but why? =)

Comment: Do you mind translating your strings to English? And side note, I'm going to _strongly_ discourage the use of `goto` in your code.

Comment: I used goto because I didn't knew what else would get the same results 

also for the strings
inlognaam = loginname 
gebruikersnaam = username
wachtwoord = password

Comment: Since you are a student, you may be wondering why everyone is saying "don't use `goto`".  Goto has been around forever, and it didn't take long for folks to abuse it.  In 1968, Edsger Dijkstra wrote a famous letter entitled "Goto Statement Considered Harmful".  You can read up about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful.  It's rare to find `goto` in modern code (though some automatic code generators will produce it - those tools generally know what they are doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labeled statements are just "usual" statements which can be "targeted" via `goto` (which you should avoid to use) and will be executed in the normal flow of the program, i.e. they are not limited  to be only reachable via go to. One way to handle the situation is to use `return`:

```
//...
Console.WriteLine("U heeft geen poginen meer, de applicatie sluit af na 5 seconden");
return;
AfterLoop:
   // ...
```

But just introducing the variable and acting accordingly is much better option:

```
bool validPasswordEntered = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // ...
    // If else login / password
    if (inlognaam == gebruikersnaam && password == wachtwoord)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Succes");
        Console.WriteLine("Druk een knop in om door tegaan");
        validPasswordEntered = true;
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist probeer opnieuw.");
}

if (validPasswordEntered)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Menu");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("U heeft geen poginen meer, de applicatie sluit af na 5 seconden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the fault is the goto, since the AfterLoop is still going to execute even if you dont call it

I recommend avoid using goto at all and just make a new method AfterLoop();

However, if you still wanna use it for some reason, add Environment.Exit(0); right after the thread.sleep to close the app after the delay.

Cheers!